# Getting "You can not share this item because it has been flagged as inappropriate" while creating permissions for a file from a Google Service Account

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-drive-api, google-developers-console, google-drive-shared-drive

I'm uploading a file to Google Drive using a Google Service Account. File is getting uploaded successfully.
But I need to share it with some stakeholders. So, while adding permissions to it, i'm getting this error: **"message": "Bad Request. User message: "You cannot share this item because it has been flagged as inappropriate."**

My code snippets are:

```
// create and return credential
private static Credential getCredentials2() throws IOException {
    
    java.io.File serviceAccountCredsFile = new java.io.File("creds.json");
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.fromStream(new FileInputStream(serviceAccountCredsFile))
            .createScoped(SCOPES);
    
    return credential;
}

// build and return an authorized drive client service
public static List<File> getDriveService() throws Exception {
    final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();

    // Instantiating a client
    Drive service = new Drive.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, getCredentials2())
                .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                .build();
    
    System.out.println("Successfully created the Drive service!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");

    
    /***************************Uploading file on Google Drive Start*********************************/
    File fileMetadata = new File();
    fileMetadata.setName("1stFile.csv");
    fileMetadata.setParents(Collections.singletonList("10Tt3rfkaeHr1JOUQYRPTfqQQ2jdDJcy")); 
    fileMetadata.setDescription("Testing upload");
    fileMetadata.setMimeType("application/csv");        
    
    java.io.File fileTobeUploaded = new java.io.File("custid.csv");
    
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(fileTobeUploaded);
    InputStreamContent mediaContent = new InputStreamContent("application/csv", inputStream);

    try {
      File uploadedFile = service.files().create(fileMetadata, mediaContent)
                                .setSupportsAllDrives(true) 
                                .execute();
com.google.api.services.drive.model.Permission newPermission = new com.google.api.services.drive.model.Permission() ;
      newPermission.setType("user");
      newPermission.setRole("writer");
      newPermission.setEmailAddress("xyz@xyz.com");
        
      service.permissions().create(createdFileId, newPermission)
                .setSupportsAllDrives(true)
                .execute();
```

After the execution of 'service.permissions().create()', i'm getting below error:

400 Bad Request
POST https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/16-wFWifo0HNZW6W1lujJiT1HO-1wLbK/permissions?supportsAllDrives=true
{
"code": 400,
"errors": [
{
"domain": "global",
"message": "Bad Request. User message: "You cannot share this item because it has been flagged as inappropriate."",
"reason": "invalidSharingRequest"
}
],
"message": "Bad Request. User message: "You cannot share this item because it has been flagged as inappropriate.""
}

Really need inputs in this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Try setting the [`sendNotificationEmail`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create#sendNotificationEmail) to `false` when creating file permissions. This solved it for me allthough I am not quite sure what caused the error in the first place. Could have something to do with the service account's settings but I am just guessing. According to [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/handle-errors#resolve_a_400_error_invalid_sharing_request) the error can happen for several reasons but does not explicitly mention a solution for this specific message.

Hopefully this will help you!

Comment: But then how will the other person automatically know you shared anything with them if they dont have google account

Answer (score 0):

Before clicking the "send" button, you might try unchecking the "Notify people" button.

By default, the "Notify people" button remains checked. You can uncheck the button and try.
It worked for me.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34493355)